# Google FCM firebase-admin initializeApp() error in K8S cluster

Tags: node.js, firebase, kubernetes, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building NodeJs server and trying to leverage FCM for push notifications. Locally everything works as expected, but in the K8S cluster I receive the following error

```
FirebaseAppError: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Missing error payload".

errorInfo: {
    code: 'app/invalid-credential',
    message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Missing error payload".'
  },
  codePrefix: 'app'
```

I tried to initialize app without arguments admin.initializeApp(), keeping env var with path json key in a config object, the path is valid, the file is present, the env is printed out ok.
I tried like this `const firebase = admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(), });` which is obviuoely the same thing. I Tried to explicitly pass credential prop with json certificate like so `const firebase = initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.cert(cert) });`
cert is present. I even tried to downgrade from firebase-admin from 10 to 9.
Node 12
please help

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue. It was DNS settings of my K8S cluster. So it didn't have proper access to the outside world (check /etc/resolv.conf inside the pod)
Had to add dns settings to my deployment declaration like so

```
      containers:
        ...
      dnsPolicy: "None"
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers:
         - 10.96.0.10 // for inner services lookup
         - 8.8.8.8
        searches:
         - default.svc.cluster.local
         - svc.cluster.local
         - cluster.local
```